# read csv in a for loop using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

```
inp_file=os.getcwd() 
files_comp = pd.read_csv(inp_file,"B00234*.csv", na_values = missing_values, nrows=10)

for f in files_comp:

    df_calculated = pd.read_csv(f, na_values = missing_values, nrows=10)
    col_length=len(df.columns)-1
```

Hi folks, How can I read 4 csv files in a for a loop. I am getting an error while reading the CSV in above format. Kindly help me

Comment: Please include the error you are getting in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need this:

1. Get a list of all target files. `files=os.listdir(path)` and then keep only the filenames that start with your pattern and end with `.csv`.
   You could also improve it using regular expression (by importing `re` library for more sophistication, or use `glob.glob`).

```py
filesnames = os.listdir(path)
filesnames = [f for f in filesnames if (f.startswith("B00234") and f.lower().endswith(".csv"))]
```

2. Read in files using a for loop:

```py
dfs = list()
for filename in filesnames:
     df = pd.read_csv(filename)
     dfs.append(df)
```

## Complete Example

We will first make some dummy data and then save that to some `.csv` and `.txt` files. Some of these `.csv` files will begin with `"B00234"` and some other would not. We will write the dumy data to these files. And then selectively only read in the `.csv` files into a list of dataframes, **`dfs`**.

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

# Define Temporary Output Folder
path = './temp_output'

# Clean Temporary Output Folder
import shutil
reset = True
if os.path.exists(path) and reset:
    shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)

# Create Content
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

display(df0)

# Make Path
import os
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
else:
    print('Path Exists: {}'.format(path))

# Make Filenames
filenames = list()
for i in range(10):
    if i<5:
        # Create Files starting with "B00234"
        filenames.append("B00234_{}.csv".format(i))
        filenames.append("B00234_{}.txt".format(i))
    else:
        # Create Files starting with "B00678"
        filenames.append("B00678_{}.csv".format(i))
        filenames.append("B00678_{}.txt".format(i))

# Create files
# Make files with extensions: .csv and .txt
#            and file names starting 
#            with and without: "B00234"
for filename in filenames:
    fpath = path + '/' + filename
    if filename.lower().endswith(".csv"):
        df0.to_csv(fpath, index=False)
    else:
        with open(fpath, 'w') as f:
            f.write(df0.to_string())

# Get list of target files
files = os.listdir(path)
files = [f for f in files if (f.startswith("B00234") and f.lower().endswith(".csv"))]
print('\nList of target files: \n\t{}\n'.format(files))

# Read each csv file into a dataframe
dfs = list() # a list of dataframes
for csvfile in files:
    fpath = path + '/' + csvfile
    print("Reading file: {}".format(csvfile))
    df = pd.read_csv(fpath)
    dfs.append(df)
```

The list `dfs` should have five elements, where each is dataframe read from the files.

**Ouptput**:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9

List of target files: 
    ['B00234_3.csv', 'B00234_4.csv', 'B00234_0.csv', 'B00234_2.csv', 'B00234_1.csv']

Reading file: B00234_3.csv
Reading file: B00234_4.csv
Reading file: B00234_0.csv
Reading file: B00234_2.csv
Reading file: B00234_1.csv
```

Comment: First print out the list of filenames you get using os.listdir(path) and check if any such file exists or not.

Comment: @MariappanM try now. It should work. Please **copy as-is**. The text in the code block earlier had a formatting issue with `"`.

Comment: @MariappanM Made a small change. Please try now. Did it work?

Comment: @MariappanM Thank you for `accepting` this answer. Could you please also **`upvote`** it?