# Skiping rows for certain files while reading the files in a loop in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read 17 files in a loop where I want to skip 1 row for few files but not for others.

Using the code as given below

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
path=os.getcwd()
files=os.listdie(os.curdir)
files_xls=[f for f in files if f[-3]=='xls']
filenames=glob.glob(path + "/.xls")
for f in files_xls:
     data=pd.read_excel(f, (skiprows==1 if data.iloc[0]==range(1, 68,1)])
```

I  know the code is incomplete and wrong in last line but my first goal is to able to write the code for skiping rows for few not all files.

Please help me write the code to skip the row.

For eg
few sample data looks like below

1       2      3

Name   Age    Sex

one     23     M

two     32     F

three    46    M

And some sample look like this

Name   Age   Sex

four   67    M

five   78    F

six    89     M

and Final output should look like this

Name   Age    Sex

one     23    M

two     32    F

three   46    M

four   67    M

five   78     F

six    89     M

P.S. I am new to programming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a sample input with output.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Edited the question. New to stackoverflow cannot upload picture. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can do something like this:

```
data=pd.read_excel(f, skiprows==1 if condition else 0)
```

But you can't use the data in the file before you read it. The condition can't be function of data (at least you don't read it before in some another way)

Note that in your loop you override the variable data in each call to `pd.read_excel`.
To read files in a loop to DataFrame see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071982/read-csv-in-a-for-loop-using-pandas).